# Why can't I build for ios from windows?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an problem error when building for ios from my windows

`UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)`

Comment: Welcome to SO Jhordan. A bit more information than that would be helpful to getting this question answered. What did you do, what relevent settings did you chose etc? You need to show effort and research - even it it seems obvious to you, we don't have your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't build unity project to IOS in windows os. You can try virtual machine to build ios, but i would recommend you better used mac to build ios.